# ZXing integration set scan_mode

Tags: android, zxing

I have integrated the ZXing source into my app, however I'm not using the Intent method to load the camera, instead I'm including the capture.xml in my layout:

`<include layout="@layout/capture"/>`

Which then embeds ZXing in my layout, I wonder how to set the SCAN_MODE to 1D code only?

Comment: That is not soo easy you need to call their activity.

Comment: Some hints on how to do that :) or even, how I can modify the decoder code, i only need to scan 1D

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard intent add this key value pair to your intent:

```
intent.putExtra(Intents.FORMATS, Intents.ONE_D_MODE);
```

In my program I used this line to limit the barcodes to QR-Codes:

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "QR_CODE");
```

See also line 36 of [this source file](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java#36).

Comment: I'm not using the intent though...is there a way to set it?